# css scrollable div after screen is less that 1025px

Tags: css

Is there a way so if a user changes there screen size to less than a certain pixel e.g. 1025px the div will then be scrollable?

I have had a search but I cannot seem to find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 1025px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) { 
  /** STYLES FOR SMALLER SCREENS HERE **/
  body { padding:0px; } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure but I feel like it would come automatically as long as scrolling isn't disabled for your div and the position isn't fixed.